# How to make flutter nested list scrollable separately from the page without using SizedBox

Tags: flutter

I'm learning flutter and faced looking simple issue but apparently it became hard to solve.
Code below targets flutter web page, so bear in mind.
I designed a page with:

- Some static text/widgets first
- Then scrollable list view. Imagine scrollable code block in the middle of the page for example. Only this block is scrolling when user scrolls it. And once block reaches the end then rest of the page is scrolling.
- And then some scrollable page continuation. Whole page is scrolling in that case.

Code below represents all these requirements.
Both nested list and page are scrollable separately.
However it has hardcoded SizedBox with harcoded height.
Also Slivers in my example are used to avoid shrinkWrap for better performance.

How can I use nested list without harcoded height? Just make it scrollable if it does not fit into the visible space.
And when it reaches the end, then continue scrolling the rest of the page.

[Dartpad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=bba9832dd2285f9985da98b9fbb394be) to try it out.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(NestedCustomScrollViewApp());
}

class NestedCustomScrollViewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Demo', home: MyNestedCustomScrollView());
  }
}

class MyNestedCustomScrollView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Text("Some top text")),
          // Nested list
          // I want it to scroll separately from the page
          // And continue whole page scrolling when this list reaches the end
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text("Nested $index"));
                }, childCount: 50))
              ],
            ),
          )),
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text("Item $index"));
          }, childCount: 50)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use shrinkwap and table.
But most common scenario is nested list is not scrollable on itself. Only the whole page scrolls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
After reading about flutter layouts and doing experiments I implemented following working code.
[DartPad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=555c8fc9ee2cba42c777219a1237709d) to try it out

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(NestedCustomScrollViewApp());
}

class NestedCustomScrollViewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedCustomScrollViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo', home: MyNestedCustomScrollView());
  }
}

class MyNestedCustomScrollView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyNestedCustomScrollView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
        const SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text("SomeText")),
        const SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text("SomeText")),
        const NestedSliverList(childrenCount: 50),
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
          return ListTile(title: Text("Item $index"));
        }, childCount: 50))
      ]),
    );
  }
}

/// SliveList designed to nesting into existing CustomScrollView.
/// Calculates it's own height as remained screen height after all previous widgets.
class NestedSliverList extends StatelessWidget {
  final int childrenCount;
  const NestedSliverList({super.key, required this.childrenCount});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverLayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, SliverConstraints constraints) {
      double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      // total height of elements above
      double prevHeight = constraints.precedingScrollExtent;
      // limit nested list height to the remained screen area
      double listHeight = screenHeight - prevHeight;
      print("Screen height= $screenHeight, nestedListHeight=$listHeight");
      return SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: SizedBox(
        height: listHeight,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          slivers: [
            SliverPrototypeExtentList(
                prototypeItem: const ListTile(title: Text("Nested")),
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text("Nested $index"));
                }, childCount: childrenCount))
          ],
        ),
      ));
    });
  }
}
```

All my initial requirements are met here:

1. Nested sliver list is scrolling without scrolling whole page.
2. Once nested list scrolling reaches the end then the whole page starts scrolling.
3. And because slivers are used all , only visible
   elements of nested sliverlist are rendered.

The key part of this implementation was to pass height constraint to the nested sliver list.It makes it scrollable without scrolling the whole page.
Passing height is achieved by wrapping nested sliver list with `SliverLayoutBuilder`.
`SliverLayoutBuilder` exposes the calculated height of all elements located above nested list as `constraints.precedingScrollExtent`.
I give my nested sliver list all remaining height on the screen as maximum height by subtracting `precedingScrollExtent` from total screen height.

CustomScrollView of the nested sliver list has shrinkWrap=true. This allows to shrink the list height if total height of it's elements is less than remain screen size. I assume this should be no overhead at all because my example is using `SliverPrototypeExtentList` which does not need to layout it's children to get total height according to [SliverPrototypeExtentList doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPrototypeExtentList-class.html). Would be awesome if someone confirms if its really the case.